# How to "convert" running Ubuntu server to boot able ISO

Tags: 12.04, server, vmware, iso

I have an Ubuntu 12.04.3 server, I have configured the server and customized the packages inside a VM(VMware Virtual Machine) and now I need to "Remaster" the system so that I would be able to export the machine as a "new" distribution inside our company.

Here is my problem, all the known re-mastering tools require a graphical component to initiate ubiquity, as this is a server, it does not have any graphical MW installed, so, how can I achive that?

Also, I've read about an option to chroot into the ISO file, will that be a good path to follow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long research I found the only working solution is using Mondo Rescue: http://www.mondorescue.org/
This does not "Remaster" the OS but, let you reinstall it on any new HD and hardware.

For now, this is my best solution.